# How to set :hover color to normal color with Less?

Tags: css, less

I have a component `jl-btn` which can have different `color` (CSS property here) depending on the other classes it may be affected by. Those classes can be used with a `<a>` element and I'd like, in one Less statement, to say that the `:hover` and `:focus` color must be the same as normal state.

```
.jl-btn {
  color: blue;

  &.jl-btn-important {
    color: red;
  }

  &:hover, &:focus {
    color: ???,
    text-decoration: none
  }
}
```

I tried to set `color` to `inherit` or `initial` but it sets it to black.
What I'd like is the :hover and :focus color to be red if there is the `jl-btn-important` class, blue if not.

Any idea ?

**[Edit]** My bad, I forgot to tell I'm using bootstrap's scaffolding that defines a style for `a:hover, a:focus`

Comment: Why not avoid the `color` setting under `:hover` and `:focus`? Does that not produce the same effect as you need? I haven't tested but I think it should.

Comment: He wants to set the color to blue when .jl-btn-important is hovered too I suppose.

Comment: @Harry it works if my classes are set on a `<div>` but not in case it's a `<a>` :(

Comment: @ValLeNain: Are you sure you aren't setting some other value elsewhere? And am I correct in saying you want color to be red when `.jl-btn-important` class is present even while hovering and focusing?

Comment: @Harry my bad, I'm using bootstrap's scaffolding that defines a style for a:hover and a:focus. And yes I'd like it to be red when hover + jl-btn-important

Comment: Oh ok. In that case you'd need to over-ride that behavior. Have a look at the second option I've added to my answer. `:extend` would be a overkill if it is as simple as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** (*If no other setting is over-riding the default behavior*)

Ideally not adding any `color` setting under the `:hover` and `:focus` selectors itself should work. The below snippet is proof for that. But if it is not working then there is some other selector overriding it.

```css
.jl-btn {
  color: blue;
}
.jl-btn.jl-btn-important {
  color: red;
}
.jl-btn:hover,
.jl-btn:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class='jl-btn' href='#'>Hello</a>
<a class='jl-btn jl-btn-important' href='#'>Hello</a>
```

---

**Option 2:** (*If some other selector is over-riding the default behavior like Bootstrap or other library*)

In which case, you could modify your Less code to be like below. This would apply the same colors to the default, `:hover` and `:focus` selectors without having to repeat the `color` under each selector.

```css
.jl-btn {
  &, &:hover, &:focus{
    color: blue;
  }
  &.jl-btn-important {
    &, &:hover, &:focus {
      color: red;
    }
  }
  &:hover, &:focus {
    text-decoration: none
  }
}
```

The below snippet is based on the compiled CSS output of the above Less code.

```css
.jl-btn,
.jl-btn:hover,
.jl-btn:focus {
  color: blue;
}
.jl-btn.jl-btn-important,
.jl-btn.jl-btn-important:hover,
.jl-btn.jl-btn-important:focus {
  color: red;
}
.jl-btn:hover,
.jl-btn:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class='jl-btn' href='#'>Hello</a>
<a class='jl-btn jl-btn-important' href='#'>Hello</a>
```

---

**Option 3:** (*If you have multiple modifiers and want to avoid writing it manually*)

If you feel that writing the selectors multiple times is also unnecessary repetition then you could write a mixin (like in the below code block), make it set the `color` for all the required selectors.

```css
.jl-btn {
  .set-anchor-colors(blue); /* mixin to set default, hover and focus color */
  &.jl-btn-important {
    .set-anchor-colors(red); /* mixin to set default, hover and focus color */
  }
  &:hover, &:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

.set-anchor-colors(@color){
  &, &:hover, &:focus{
    color: @color;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's the result I'm looking for but the problem is that I have more that modifier class (i.e. `jl-btn-important`,`jl-btn-reverse`,...) that's why I was looking for a way to it in one statement inside the `.jl-btn { }` declaration

Comment: @ValLeNain: In that case you either need to do the same as what I've done for all the modifiers (or) use JavaScript (or) at the most write a mixin and keep invoking it. I don't think you could do anything else.

Comment: @ValLeNain: I've added an option 3 also which should atleast avoid the repetition for you but it affects readability imo.

Answer (score 0):

```
.jl-btn {
    color: blue;
    &.jl-btn-important {
        color: red;
        &:hover,
        &:focus {
            &:extend(.jl-btn);
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind extend copies all css properties not just color.

You could also use a variable for the property value blue.